# Local run in Azure ML SDK 2

Tags: python, azuremlsdk

I want to upgrade the local run of my project to SDK 2 based on *[Upgrade local runs to SDK v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-local-runs?view=azureml-api-2)*:

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration

if run_type == "local":
    custom_env_name = 'azure_ml_sdk2'
    myenv = Environment(
    image='mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04',
    conda_file='conda.yml',
    name=custom_env_name,
  )
```

But I get this error:

```
Docker was not found on the target, check that it is installed and on the path.

[2023-05-08T15:16:21.404591] Logging error in history service: SystemExit: 1
```

I checked both the installation and the path. What is the problem?